# Getting a memory error when using birch algorithm in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

The shape of given input numpy array is (463277, 38). and I am doing something like

```
brc = Birch(threshold=0.5,n_clusters=None)
brc.fit_transform(X)
```

but getting a memory error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-d906f45761a4> in <module>
     1 brc = Birch(threshold=0.5)
----> 2 brc.fit_transform(X)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
   551         if y is None:
   552             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 553             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
   554         else:
   555             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)



MemoryError:
```

Comment: It's like what it says. A memory error. You need to run the program in a system with better specs.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you are using scikit-learn. This is an issue that has been resolved
[here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16027).

Try updating your scikit-learn module using

`$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`